# How to match the whole expression only, even when there are sub parts that match?

Tags: regex

Just trying to write input validation pattern that would allow entry of wild characters. Input field is 9 char max and should follow these rules:

```
 * + 1- 8 charcters
 1- 8 chars + *
 * + 1-7 chars + *
```

I've written this regex using the regex documentation and testing it on one of the regex testers.

> `\*{1}[0-9]{1,7}\*{1}|[0-9]{1,8}\*{1}|\*{1}[0-9]{1,8}|[0-9]{9}`

It matches all these correctly

```
123456789
*1*
*12*
*123*
*1234*
*12345*
*123456*
*1234567*
1234567*
123456*
12345*
1234*
123*
12*
1*
*1
*12
*123
*1234
*12345
*123456
*1234567
*12345678
```

But  it also matches when I don't want it. For example it finds 2 matches in this `*123456789*` First match is `*12345678` and second one is `9*`

I don't want in this case to find any matches. Either the whole string matches one of the patterns or not. How does one do that?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using that doesn't require you to escape the asterisk?

Comment: oops sorry, copy paste error

Comment: here is a good tool for writing regular expressions.
https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that make sure the regex always matches the entire string:

```
^(\*[0-9]{1,7}\*|[0-9]{1,8}\*|\*[0-9]{1,8}|[0-9]{9})$
```

Note the parentheses to make sure that the alternation is contained within the group:

```
^
(
 \*[0-9]{1,7}\*
|
 [0-9]{1,8}\*
|
 \*[0-9]{1,8}
|
 [0-9]{9}
)
$
```

Also, `{1}` is always superfluous - one match per token is the default.

Answer (score -1):

You could use start and end string anchors:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

So, your regex would be something like this (note first and last symbol):

```
^(\*{1}[0-9]{1,7}*{1}|[0-9]{1,8}*{1}|*{1}[0-9]{1,8}|[0-9]{9})$
```

Comment: This won't work correctly. You need to use parentheses to limit the scope of the alternation.